# ngx-datatable: Column not sortable when using headerTemplate?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

Angular 8 and ngx-datatable 16.0.2:

I've started using ngx-datatable and am faced with some challenges getting sort to work when I use a headerTemplate. My column definition is like this:

```
this.columns = [
  {
    prop: 'name',
    name: 'Navn',
    headerTemplate: this.headerTpl,
    flexGrow: 3
  },
  ...
];
```

My headerTemplate is declared like this:

```
@ViewChild('headerTpl', null) headerTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and in my HTML:

```
  <ng-template #headerTpl let-column="column">
    <div class="column-headlines">{{ column.name }}</div>
  </ng-template>
```

The issue is that the css from the class `column-headlines` is applied but the column is not sortable. When I remove `headerTemplate: this.headerTpl` from my column definition sort works just fine (but styling is of course wrong). What am I missing here?

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rii739) where I would have expected my column header to have been styled AND sortable.

It all seems to be tied to the use of the template. As soon as that's in play, everything else goes haywire...

Comment: Can u provide minimal stackblitz?

Comment: Added StackBlitz to OP

Answer (score 3):

There is a closed issue in ngx-datatable's github project: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/1807

It says you have to add a `let-sort="sortFn"` to the ng-template and insert a `(click)="sort()"` to its content. If you also want the mouse cursor to change you can insert `class="datatable-header-cell-wrapper"` to the content.

```
<!-- header templates-->
<ng-template #hdrTmpl let-sort="sortFn">
    <span class="datatable-header-cell-wrapper" (click)="sort()">
        header content goes here
    </span>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `this.headerTpl` is not set yet at constructor time. This will be available at the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, (or `ngOnInit` if you use `{static: true}`):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.columns = [{
    prop: 'name',
    name: 'Navn',
    headerTemplate: this.headerTpl
  }]
}
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uspbqy?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Okay so I've tried moving my columns initialization to ngAfterViewInit() but no change. The actual template is applied but the column is still not sortable. I've even tried adding sortable: true to the column definition. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I've updated my original StackBlitz. Moved columns init to ngAfterViewInit() and sorting stops working :-(